# Android Studio doesn't start with connected device

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio v0.1 on Mac. My project imported and built successfully. AVD shows up whenever I run or debug the project, even though my device is connected and shown in integrated DDMS. I have double checked with `adb devices` from command-line and it shows my connected device. Please help~

Answer (score 48, accepted):

// the very First time it will always selected only emulator options

you need to change it in Create Run Configuration...
in that General Tab select Target Device

- Show chooser dialog
- USB Devices
- Emulator

Comment: Thanks! I've found the General tab from the menu `Run` and then `Edit Configuration` on Mac

Comment: How can I make it choose device first time around, without changing this setting?

Comment: @powder366 Its by default selection its selected Emulator only. without changing it you cannot run thru Android Studio.

Answer (score 7):

Visual aid to @Padma Kumar's answer.

[image: Select The Configurations]

[image: Change Android Application Configuration Settings]

"Android Studio is not starting from Device", "Force to start Android Studio from Device"