# Android studio and device external

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to emulate an app with an external device in android studio? I have a device connected to the computer, but when you run the app it does not recognize the device.

Note: The mode and debugging mode to accept unknown sources are activated.

Comment: you want to lunch your app in your device?

Comment: Can you do same with eclipse? It is probably drivers problem, not Android studio

Comment: click on run -> edit configuration -> android application. show chooser dialog should be selected

Comment: Android Studio doesn't start with connected device http://stackoverflow.com/q/16585055/1012284

Answer (score 19):

Go to the run configuration of your module and change that:

[image]

There you can choose weather you want to launch it in an emulator, device or if IntelliJ should ask you every time when you run it:

[image]

Comment: thanks guys, I used path: run -> edit configuration -> Target device. and everything worked normally

thanks again

Comment: @Androidz If the answer solved your problem, click the green check mark on the left to mark it as the correct answer. That's the Stack Overflow way of saying thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install driver from Google - http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html
It helped for me

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problems and i have been surfing the net for hours to figure what is wrong. In my case the solution was that Android Studio has a default targeted-API 16 and my Huawei runs android 4.0.4 which is API 15.

Change it in the AndroidManifest and it should run properly!!

```
android:targetSdkVersion="15"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check driver for your portable device is installed or not. To do so,

1. Right click on My Computer or This Pc
2. Click on the properties
3. In the left, click device manager.
4. Now find out whether your device is connected properly under portable device section.
5. If not then try to install suitable driver for your device according your System.