# Android Studio doesn't send a match code for my device

Tags: android, android-studio

I see there are some similar questions(you may check the links below) but none of them answers my question. I have installed Android Studio many times and used 2 different phones before. 3 days ago I had to factory reset my PC and than I reinstalled Android Studio. I connected my Galaxy S4 but adb doesn't see it. **BUT MY QUESTION IS** before this occasion whenever I plug in a device it was sending me an USB debugging authorization code. This time it doesn't happen. Why I don't receive an authorization code ?

**Here's some similar questions which helped none.** Yes I almost have the same problem but one says AS starts project with virtual device other says I see my device is running but it doesn't work.

> [Android Studio doesn't see device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596877/android-studio-doesnt-see-device)
>
> [Android studio doesn't list my phone under "Choose Device"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225927/android-studio-doesnt-list-my-phone-under-choose-device)
>
> [Android Studio doesn't start with connected device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585055/android-studio-doesnt-start-with-connected-device)

Also I did a google research found something about Google USB Driver which is already installed on my SDK. So it didn't help me either. Here's the link:

> http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

So I am hopeless. I tried everything. ADB doesn't see my device. **But my real question is before you *downgrade* or say it is *duplicate* why I don't receive an USB debugging authorization code?** Thanks for checking! If you could help me I would very appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google USB-Driver is for Nexus devices only.

If you want to use a Samsung device you need to download and install the needed driver.
A list of all supported retailers can be [found here.](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers)

After you've downloaded the driver simply install it as [described here.](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7)

Then you can activate the "USB debugging" mode on your device. It can be found under "developer options". 
If you don't see this category simply tap the "build number field" 7 times.

Comment: Thank you so much! After I installed USB driver I received the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need restart android device, android ADB. After that, reconnect android device to PC, it will be automaticaly installed proper USB driver.